# Why don't people like my tags? :(

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-abuse

I've been recently using the `[and-then-i-began-to-cry]`(which GMan created) tag and Jeff recently has been untagging my questions. What's wrong Jeff? Do you have no feelings?

It's ok. You can cry on my shoulder. You don't have to hide the pain.

Comment: @Jona :( sad face

Comment: _I_ like your tags.

Comment: @Len *sniff* thank *sniff* you.

Answer (score 14):

Meta is relaxed, but creating ( and using frequently ) these types of tags is simply chaotic, and will ruin what little fabric Meta maintains, IMHO. I understand and appreciate the need for fun, but the manner in which fun is appropriately incorporated must be massaged and explored - playing with tags probably isn't the best method of letting loose.

Comment: but it's all on joke questions anyway.

Comment: If you ask me, when the joke questions outnumber (or even compete with) the serious questions, we begin to see the horizon of a serious problem. Just my opinion though.

Comment: What was that about having fun massaging and exploring?

Comment: @JonB Have you ever written something only to read it a minute later and think, "Oh man, somebody's going to read that differently..." :)

Comment: massaging?  @Jon, are you offering or requesting?

Comment: Where's the fun in crying?

Comment: Drinking the victim's tears. @ivo

Answer (score 5):

Because real programmers don't cry.

They express their sorrow using infinite loops which makes the computer's CPU melt.

Comment: @ChaCha you are evil

Comment: `while true; do say "I cried"; done`

Comment: @Josh: You missed a semicolon on the last line :)

Comment: @George: Actually it works with or without the semicolon. ;)

Comment: @Josh: In what language? jQuery?!?

Comment: @George jQuery isn't a language, it is a library.

Comment: @Cha @Geo it is for this reason people should not use memes they do not understand :)

Comment: @Earlz: Who doesn't understand?

Comment: @George if you have to ask.... lol

Comment: @Josh - _Real_ programmers write `++++++++++[>>++++++++++<<-]>>[->+>+>+>+>+<<<<<]<<++++++++++[>+++++++>+++>>+>>>>+<<<<<<<<-]>+++>++>->++++>+++++>+<<<<<[.>.>.>.>.>.>.>.<<<<<<<]`. And they write it correctly the first time.

Comment: ...unlike I did. Change `++++++++++[>>++++++++++<<-]>>` to `>++++++++++[>++++++++++<-]>` to shave a few characters and cycles.

Comment: @Josh, `;` right after `true` is a bug. `do say` won't be executed :)

Comment: @Nick, @All: I'm not sure what you're talking about, but it works in bash.... so yeah....

Answer (score 1):

Because [Jeff hates fun](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/).

Answer (score 1):

Because multiple uses of the tag without matching `[In-The-End-I-Decided-It-Was-Futile]` tags creates Tear-Overflow errors and floods the servers.